# 403 при запросе в Геокодер API Яндекс.Карт

Tags: php, yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь получить гео-координаты из php-скрипта:

```
$params = array(
        'geocode' => 'Москва, ул. Льва Толстого, 16', // адрес
        'format' => 'json', // формат ответа
        'results' => 1, // количество выводимых результатов
        'key' => 'de30b30e-aba5-4091-a796-xxx' // ваш api key
    );

    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?' . http_build_query($params, '', '&')));

    if ($response->response->GeoObjectCollection->metaDataProperty->GeocoderResponseMetaData->found > 0) {
        echo $response->response->GeoObjectCollection->featureMember[0]->GeoObject->Point->pos;
    } else {
        echo 'Ничего не найдено<br>';
    }
```

Получаем "Ничего не найдено".

Выводим url с параметрами, и вставляем его в адресную строку. Получаем:

```
{"statusCode":403,"error":"Forbidden","message":"Key is required"}
```

Что как бы гвоорит нам о том, что мы не указали API ключ, хотя мы его указали.

Выводим `print_r($response)` вообще пусто! `file_get_contents` с другим url работает. Делаю вывод, возможно неправильный -

```
file_get_contents(
  'https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?' .
   http_build_query($params, '', '&')
)
```

не работает, хотя http-запрос формируется правильно. При этом совсем непонятно, почему при копировании http-запроса и отправке его через адресную строку браузера получаем сообщение о том, что мы не указали ключ. В кабинете разработчика Яндекса видим, что API ключ активный.

Есть соображения на этот счет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я вижу - не `key`, а `apikey`

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage/

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&geocode=Москва,+Тверская+улица,+дом+7
```

Попробуйте минимально простой запрос из их документации с вашим ключом и отлаживайте дальше свой код исходя из результатов.

Comment: Спасибо! Чуть мозг не вывернул)